# какой Java JDK нужен для android studio 3.6.3

Tags: android-studio, jdk11

Какой Java JDK нужен для android studio 3.6.3 ? Спасибо.

Comment: Нет особых требований.

Comment: Уважаемый Эникейщик, когда-то установил JDK 12, возникли недорозумения. Пришлось устанавливать 10

Comment: в АС уже встроен jdk